# Remote Access to Custom Local groups - Windows

Tags: windows

I have created a local Group named "testusers" and have added one user "user01" into the group. Now what I want is to grant remote access to all the user in this group. Upon some research I concluded that this can be achieved by going to

> "ControlPanel --> Administrative Tools --> Local Security Policy -->
>   Local Policies --> UserRightsAssignment --> Allow Logon through Remote
>   Desktop services--> Add my group".

But the above solution did not work for me. Is there any other way to achieve this or is this possible even firstplace?

Comment: Did you set your PC\username correctly? If you connect with local user, you need to use `computername\user`.

Comment: @Lenniey Yes I tried that too. No luck but.

Comment: `solution did not work for me`. What error is recorded in the event log?

Comment: @GregAskew Weird logs. The event logs show as if the user logged in and then immediately logged off. When I try to RDP It is going until the certificate verification and after I click Yes it is displaying the standard error message that "This user does not have the permisssion for remote login "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user needs a combination of both user rights and permissions to logon via RDP. You've granted them the appropriate user rights but you haven't granted them the appropriate permissions. The easiest way to do both is to add the users to the local Remote Desktop Users group.

Here's a breakdown of the RDP permissions, including those needed to logon via RDP:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-permissions